# Casting do retorno do malloc em matriz de Strings

Tags: c

O objetivo do programa é informar a quantidade de dias, horas, minutos e segundos correspondentes a quantidade de segundos na entrada. Caso o valor seja menor que zero, a saída deverá ter zero a esquerda do dígito.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int qtdDigitos(int n){
    int qtdDigitos = 0;
    if(n==0)
        return qtdDigitos;
    else
        while (n != 0){
            qtdDigitos++;
            n/=10;
        }
    return qtdDigitos;
}
char *converteString(int n){
    int qDigitos = qtdDigitos(n);
    char *str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(qDigitos+1));
    int m;
    char c;
    for (int i = (qDigitos-1); i >= 0; i--){
        if(n>=10){
            m = n%10;
            n/=10;
        }
        else if(n<10)
            m = n;
        c = m+'0';
        str[i] = c;

    }
    c = n+'0';
    str[0] = c;
    str[qDigitos]= '\0';
    return str;
}

int main(){
    int dadosInteiros[4], segundos;
    char **dadosString = (char **)malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
    int ret = scanf("%d", &segundos);
    if(ret!=1 || segundos<0)
        printf("ERRO\n");
    else{
        dadosInteiros[0] = segundos/86400;
        segundos %= 86400;
        dadosInteiros[1] = segundos/3600;
        segundos %= 3600;
        dadosInteiros[2] = segundos/60;
        segundos %= 60;
        dadosInteiros[3] = segundos;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            if(dadosInteiros[i]>=10){
                dadosString[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(qtdDigitos(dadosInteiros[i])+1));
                strcpy(dadosString[i], converteString(dadosInteiros[i]));
            }   
            else{
                dadosString[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
                char c = dadosInteiros[i] + '0';
                dadosString[i][1] = c;
                dadosString[i][0] = '0';
                dadosString[i][2] = '\0';
            }
            
        }
        
        printf("%sd%sh%sm%ss\n", dadosString[0], dadosString[1], dadosString[2], dadosString[3]);
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

O programa está funcionando dentro do esperado, mas estou com dúvida se o *casting* no retorno do malloc nas linhas 2 e 16 da `main` está correto. No primeiro, aloco um vetor de ponteiros do tipo `char` e, no segundo, preencho cada uma das posições com uma `string`.

Comment: Leia também https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+sizeof+char+%22sempre+1%22